# ActiveX Browser Stopped Displaying Google Maps in Access 2007

Tags: html, google-maps, activex

We are using Microsoft Access 2007 and have a form that contains an ActiveX WebBrowser to show a map within an Access form. This control is programmed to use an internal html file for Google Maps.  This worked just great on dozens of computers, tablets and PCs until just a few days ago.  It has been working for over a year.  Now it displays a blank with screen with the controls on the screen but no map.  If you zoom in or out, you will see a quick flicker of the map but then everything goes to white.  This problem is not  a problme in one company but everywhere I've tried and this also happens in Access 2010.  Something changed over the past couple of days--does anyone have an idea for a solution?

The Form_Load looks like this:
tstr = "file:///C:/TCOSMaps.html"  'Note the
Me.WebBrowser0.NAVIGATE tstr

The HTML file looks like this (standard Google sample):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #map {
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>



    <script>

    var map;
    function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 },
            zoom: 8
        });
    }

    </script>

</head>


<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC4Gv_xvPY58mlcZd6jxFAroCjnOtv4c0w&callback=initMap"
            async defer></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, it looks like this was a short term problem and it appears that the code has been fixed.  Google maps once again now works in the MS Access ActiveX WebBrowser.  There must have been a code change a week again and then a repair within the last day or so.  Note that we extensively tested the fact that this Google Maps was not working in this browser when this question was posted.  We tested on many different computers and over a variety of networks.  Great that Google could fix the problem in the end but it sure was frustrating.  In the end we ended up writing separate code to run Bing Maps in place of Google Maps so we now have a backup if that happens again.